# Fetch Bytes from Non MFI Device using MFI USB Accessory Cable

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, mfi

I want to use the MFI certified cable (same as shown in image) for fetching raw data (bytes) from ultrasonic device (not MFI certified) which will be connected to USB female port of a cable.

For now: I have a cable which is not certified, so no protocol string is appearing for that cable. So buying certified will show protocol or not?

As application is in-house so I can use any private framework/library, If there is any?

[image]